# Datatables - Row grouping with checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, datatables, grid

I have an array of the following data:

```
{"Id":1,"ProgramName":"Adobe Reader XI 
(11.0.23)","FileName":"AcroBroker.exe","FileHash":"1bfb99860246e334c00e4427b54afc3e"}
```

I want to use datatables to show a grid of this data grouped by program name with a checkbox on each row(and group name row too !), if user clicks on the checkbox of the group row all of its children will be checked, something like this but with datatables plugin !

http://jsfiddle.net/Suninsky/564RP/12/

Comment: instead of downvoting, my fellowe stackoverflowers, help me to improve the question as the stackoverflow site suggest you ! I guess you don't know the meaning of down vote, it is not I DON"T LIKE IT !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

I am the author of [jQuery DataTables Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) plug-in.

I added [example](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/integration/rowgroup/) demonstrating how jQuery DataTables Checkboxes extension can be used with RowGroup extension.

Below is an excerpt from the full code demonstrating the most important parts.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
   'orderFixed': [4, 'asc'],
   'rowGroup': {
      'dataSrc': 'office',
      'startRender': function(rows, group) {
         // Assign class name to all child rows
         var groupName = 'group-' + group.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '');
         var rowNodes = rows.nodes();
         rowNodes.to$().addClass(groupName);

         // Get selected checkboxes
         var checkboxesSelected = $('.dt-checkboxes:checked', rowNodes);

         // Parent checkbox is selected when all child checkboxes are selected
         var isSelected = (checkboxesSelected.length == rowNodes.length);

         return '<label><input type="checkbox" class="group-checkbox" data-group-name="' 
                + groupName + '"' + (isSelected ? ' checked' : '') +'> ' + group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</label>';
      }         
   }
} );

// Handle click event on group checkbox
$('#example').on('click', '.group-checkbox', function(e){
   // Get group class name
   var groupName = $(this).data('group-name');

   // Select all child rows
   table.cells('tr.' + groupName, 0).checkboxes.select(this.checked);
});

// Handle click event on "Select all" checkbox
$('#example').on('click', 'thead .dt-checkboxes-select-all', function(e){
   var $selectAll = $('input[type="checkbox"]', this);      
   setTimeout(function(){
      // Select group checkbox based on "Select all" checkbox state
      $('.group-checkbox').prop('checked', $selectAll.prop('checked'));
   }, 0);
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/2b0revo8/) for full code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

[jQuery DataTables: Row grouping and checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-row-grouping-and-checkboxes-part-2/)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, can we have support for intermediate value for parent checkboxes too? is it hard to add it?

Comment: @badzilla, it's not as simple and will require some extra thought.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue by this, I override the `startRender` of DataTables like this:

```
 rowGroup: {
                dataSrc: 'ProgramName',
                startRender: function(rows, group) {
                    rows.every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                        var rowData = this.data();
                        $(this.node()).addClass(group.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, ''));
                    });
                    return "<input type='checkbox' class='program-name-checkbox' data-program='" +
                        group.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '') + "'/>" + group + '(' + rows.count() + ')';
                }
            }
```

and by the help of this code I mark the child checkboxes when their parent is clicked:

```
   $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            $('.program-name-checkbox').on('click',
                function(event) {
                    debugger;
                    var programName = $(this).data('program');
                    var childs = $('tr.' + programName).find("input[type='checkbox']");

                    if (this.checked) {
                        childs.prop('checked', true);
                    } else {
                        childs.prop('checked', false);
                    }
                });
        });
```

**Edit:** I just found that the `checkboxes` extension of `Datatables` does not recognize thoses checkboxes that I have set pragmatically, I somehow need to use this api `cells().checkboxes.select(state)` for setting the child checkboxes.